# How to properly ground panel box if I'm replacing all copper with PEX?

Tags: plumbing, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

So I've got a 1950s house and I'm in the planning stages of a project to replace all the copper plumbing with PEX. The copper is in really bad shape, there are ancient gate valves all over the place that leak/are heavily corroded. Needless to say, none of this looks like it was ever done to code and the whole supply line is a hodgepodge of copper and PEX before it even gets to the meter (in the basement) and then random sections of galv, copper and PEX throughout the house starting around the water heater. Basically there's about 3" of 3/4" copper coming out of the wall, followed by a ball valve that goes to a couple of inches of 3/4" PEX with corroded SS clamps (photo 1), then a 90 degree fitting, then ~2' of PEX again then a SharkBite to copper to the water meter (photo 2). There's a wire in photo 2 (not the one coming from the top of the meter, I believe that runs out to the panels outside the house so that the water company can read the meter without needing to access the basement), the other wire was just laying on the ground, not connected to anything at all. Then from photo 2, past the water meter, the line runs up past all the backflow and pressure reducing valves up and right across the joists to the water heater, but before it gets to that, there's armored cable coming out the electrical panel and hooked up to the pipe directly (photo 3). On the exterior side of the house (from around where the water supply line is buried) there is a newish copper grounding rod with what looks to be 6 AWG stranded wire clamped to it (couldn't get a good photo of it because it's in an overgrown section and covered with snow but it runs to the panel from what I could gather.

Anyhow, my plan is to basically remove all the copper and run PEX as there are multiple slow leaks all over the place from most of the valves (even the pressure valve is leaking) starting from the valve in the first photo. So PEX from there, to the meter, then PEX again with the backflow, pressure reducer, etc. But then what do I do about the grounding situation for the meter and for the armored cable? That one would have nothing to be connected to and since there's the grounding rod outside, should I just install another grounding rod a few feet away from it and replace that armored cable with #6 solid wire? Or pull it from the panel and run the #6 directly to the 3" of copper sticking out from the wall and clamp it to that? But then that leaves the water meter not grounded, should I just connect it with a short length of copper wire on both sides before hooking up the PEX? But I don't see what that would accomplish since the meter would be insulated by PEX on both sides.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Most code now requires two grounding rods connected with one piece of copper wire to the panel, no splices or special non removable splices.  The meter should be able to run a ground wire to ground.

Comment: You don't have to ground the meter.  With metal piping you bridge the meter to ensure continuity through it, but the point of it is not to ground the meter.   You might be able to use the copper stub coming through the wall as one of your ground rods, since the service connection isn't (yet) PEX.   I'd ask my inspector about that.  This would be a good time to ensure all kitchen and bathroom outlets are GFCI-protected, since metal fixtures such as a stainless steel sink would now be capable of being energized without blowing a breaker.

Comment: Coper does not corrodes, it only builds surface layer of oxide, use some sanding paper and clean it to find coper under it

Comment: Hqving the 2nd ground rod near the first is not a virtue at all.  It is a cheapness.  "6 feet apart" is bare minimum. Cattycorner of the building is the ideal.   So I would look at where is easiest to run it from the panel, and if that's nice and far away, great.